# Exporting Data from Django Template to Excel

Tags: django, django-templates

I wish to do just that: Export my context data on a template to Excel, using XlsxWriter or anything of the kind. The user would click on a button or anchor on the template. If I use a url path to call a view, some sort of HttpResponse is expected. I have no idea if or how this can be done through some sort of custom tag, either (I saw this suggested elsewhere). Any ideas? Or better yet, does anyone have a project on GitHub that has anything like this? Thanks in advance.

I tried calling a url path, that would in turn call a view. But the view needs to return an HttpResponse at least. So this leaves me with 2 uncertain possibilities:

1. Can a url path simply call a module, completely independent of views.py?
2. If I do call a view, could it return something like a response to the currently-rendered template? (like "file created!", for instance. I don't want to leave the template.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the following:

```
response = HttpResponse(path, content_type=mime_type)
# Set the HTTP header for sending to browser
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
# Return the response value
return response
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the methodology here. It seems I need to learn more about Http...